# Datepicker does not insert a date

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I've run into a tricky problem it seems. I've got two input text fields that i've turned into datepickers. However when i pick a date the date does not transfer into the textfield. The calendar shows perfectly.

The project is in MVC 3 and has been programmed by some former employees. I've been looking through the code for the last couple of days now, and i've tried to change the version of jQuery. The project is running v. 1.5.1 by default. I've tried v. 1.6.4 v. 1.7.2 and v. 1.10.1, version 1.7.2 seems to be the latest valid version as the rest of the project also depend on jQuery. Later version seems to be creating some incompatibility.

Seems i've run into a wall here, and i'm hoping some of you out there can shine a little light for me.

Code defining the elements in my view:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <label><input id="enable-Periode" type="checkbox" @(Model.StartDate.HasValue || Model.EndDate.HasValue ? "checked=checked" : "") onclick="archiveMetaDataPlacement.enabledPeriod(this);" />Benyt periode</label>

    <div style="margin: 10px 0 20px 0">
        <label>Periode <input type="text" size="11" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" class="datepicker" value="@(Model.StartDate.HasValue ? Model.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString() :  "")" /></label> - 
        <label>Periode <input type="text" size="11" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" class="datepicker" value="@(Model.EndDate.HasValue ? Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "")" /></label>
    </div>
...
<script>
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
</script>
```

The jQuery scripts is importet in the coherent "masterlayout":

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/buttons-and-hovermenu.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="/Content/user/ie7fix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/json/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/admin/iportal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/global/globalization"></script>

@RenderSection("head", required: false)
```

Comment: well, will be hard without any code

Comment: try looking to see if there are any js issues, e.g use the console on chrome..

Comment: The console in chrome shows no errors sadly :S

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the help guys. However the problem is solved. Seems my old colleague had left some testmethods in the parentview, instantiating the same partialview which contained the same elements. Thereby messing up the datepickers.

Answer (score 0):

try with including this js versions

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: As described in the text above. All jQuery files of versions above 1.7.2 does not work for my project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and read Mark's answer. I went to look for other DOM elements with the same ID as the input I was trying to inject with the date. I found the input element in some test markup that was being used for design purposes. I deleted the other input and the DatePicker began to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm late to the party but I am sure if anyone have same problem this will help.
Ok, here in your case, this problem happens when you use tow or more than one inputs with same **IDs**, so there the **Datepicker** can't recognize where to put the date in.